# UDP reverse tunneling

Tags: udp, tunneling, socat

I have a problem that I am having a serious hard time figuring out, and I would be very grateful if anyone could provide some help.

I have a VPN server inside a local network behind a firewall that allows only outbound connections.
My goal it to do a “UDP gender change” and make the VPN UDP port available to an external server where I can forward ports, by creating a reverse tunnel. Doing this using a TCP tunnel is trivial and easy to accomplish by using tools such as socat, nc or even ssh tunnels. VPN, however, should always be carried by UDP packets to avoid TCP meltdown issue (TCP over TCP).

UDP reverse tunnel created with socat/nc does not work as UDP is a connectionless protocol. This means that “client client” and “listen listen” configuration will allow data transfer only when client sends a packet first (impossible in a reverse connection).

Am I missing something? Is there any utility that can accomplish this task (by for example making UDP connection oriented by the use of some headers) without using a second VPN connection?
Thank you very much

Comment: have you searched for "UDP hole punching" or any of the NAT traversal protocols to see what they do?  webrtc is another common system that seems to face similar problems, might be a place to look

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I am aware of UDP hole punching but unfortunately I have been unable to find any tool that allow its use for a reverse connection.

Comment: Both webrtc and bittorrent use hole punching in a clever way to archieve somehow similar results. The technical aspects of the tunnel are clear to me. What I am trying to find is if my problem is solvable by using existing tools (nc, socat, (...) and as far as I have been able to understand it is not) or if the only possible solution is to code a custom tunnel.

Comment: can't you just ping UDP packets to/from known ports on either side?  that might be enough to coerce a relatively dumb NATing firewall into creating a forwarding rule for you.  not sure if you have that much control over things, but might be somewhere to start

Comment: That's kind of what I was trying to do with socat. The real problem is the "reverse" part of the connection. I can establish the connection, but the first packet must be sent by the client. Is there any way to send (and discard server side) an automatic "hello" packet, to establish the UDP connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of something like this in Python:

```py
import socket
from select import select

# immediately useful parameters are:
#   REMOTE_SERVER_NAME other network server (which will be resolved by DNS)
#   LOCAL_SERVER_PORT where forward network traffic to

REMOTE_SERVER_NAME = '8.8.8.8'
LOCAL_SERVER_PORT = 20
LOCAL_SERVER_NAME = '127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_PORT = 9990
LOCAL_PORT = REMOTE_PORT + 1

sock_remote = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_remote.bind(('', REMOTE_PORT))
sock_remote.connect((REMOTE_SERVER_NAME, REMOTE_PORT))

sock_local = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_local.bind(('', LOCAL_PORT))
sock_local.connect((LOCAL_SERVER_NAME, LOCAL_SERVER_PORT))

sockets = (sock_remote, sock_local)
for s in sockets:
    s.setblocking(0)

# loop forever forwarding packets between the connections
while True:
    avail, _, _ = select((sock_local, sock_remote), (), (), timeout=100)

    # send a keep alive message every timeout
    if not avail:
        sock_remote.send(b'keep alive')
        continue

    for s in avail:
        # something from the local server, forward it on
        if s is sock_local:
            msg = sock_local.recv(8192)
            sock_remote.send(msg)

        # something from the remote server
        if s is sock_remote:
            msg = sock_remote.recv(8192)
            # don't forward keep alives to local system
            if msg != b'keep alive':
                sock_local.send(msg)
```

i.e. run this on either server (changing `REMOTE_SERVER_NAME` to point to the appropriate place) and it'll forward packets between them, sending a "keep alive" packet every 100 seconds.  your local process would send UDP packets to `LOCAL_PORT` and these would be forwarded to the remote server, the remote server would receive these and send them on to `LOCAL_SERVER_PORT` at the other end.  there are 8 flows to worry about so naming gets awkward:

```
DMZ <=> VPN <=> python <=> NAT <=> internet <=> NAT <=> python <=> VPN <=> DMZ
```

you might be able to detect the `LOCAL_SERVER_NAME` and `LOCAL_SERVER_PORT` using a `sock_local.recvfrom` and stashing the addrinfo away, but thought I'd leave them in for ease of understanding

hope you understand Python! but I was struggling to express it in words

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. The use of known ports on both sides made it unfeasible on my application, but it headed me in the right direction, and with a few modifications I was able to make it work in my environment. I will shortly post it in another answer, and I would be very grateful if you could check it for possible improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired from the python script above (and having the same VPN behind NAT problem at home) I implemented this idea in C and published it on github: https://github.com/prof7bit/udp-reverse-tunnel

Depending on the command line options this program can either act as the "inside agent" or the "outside agent".

The inside agent will open the NAT by sending keepalive packets to the outside agent and listen to incoming tunnel packets from the outside on that socket.

The outside agent will open a socket and listen for tunnel packets and for client packets on a configurable port.

Multiple VPN clients can now connect to the outside agent, every time a client has started using the tunnel the inside agent will immediately open a new spare tunnel on a new socket, so at any time there is at least one unused spare tunnel available for the outside agent to be able to immediately serve a new client.

The keepalive packets from the inside can optionally be authenticated with a simple hash based MAC (nonce + pre shared secret) to make spoofing the keepalive packet and thereby diverting the tunnel impossible.

I have been using this now for a few days and it works like a charm. As for the speed it is much faster than the initial python prototype, I can saturate my DSL line in both directions while the CPU stays idle, the outside agent is running on a cheap VPS for 2€/month.

Comment: I just want to say this answer is my feel good internet moment for the month. I've been looking for just this all day! You and the original python poster made my day :)

Comment: Just wanted to say this code worked like a charm and I was able to build it on openwrt without too many issues. Also in response to the guy who responded to the other question saying that WebRTC/STUN/TURN was the only option for people with two firewalls (one on each client). I am running precisely such a setup two clients behind symetric NATs and this seems to be working fine for me. I think this is basically equivalent to a TURN server because it's forwarding all the traffic (I think the user may have been equating this technique to  UDP hole punching which wont work for two symetric NATs)

Answer (score 1):

I adapted Sam Mason's answer to execute a UDP reverse connection.
This is the configuration:

```
HOST UDP-LISTEN <=> python cc <=> NAT <=> internet <=> server <=> python ll UDP-LISTEN
```

Host listen to a UDP port. You can reach the host from any third client that has acces to the server by using the reverse connection through the python script.
The first part is the listen listen script. It will listen for the client script on CC_PORT and will forward anything on SERVICE_PORT. It will also discard keepalive coming from the cc script.

```
import socket
from select import select

CC_PORT = 8881
SERVICE_PORT = 8880
LISTEN_IP='x.x.x.x'

sock_cc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_cc.bind((LISTEN_IP,CC_PORT))

sock_serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_serv.bind((LISTEN_IP,SERVICE_PORT))

sockets = (sock_cc, sock_serv)
for s in sockets:
    s.setblocking(0)

client_serv=None
client_cc=None

# loop forever forwarding packets between the connections
while True:
    avail, _, _ = select((sock_cc, sock_serv), (), (), 1)

    # send a keep alive message every timeout
    if not avail:
        continue

    for s in avail:
        # something from the local server, forward it on
        if s is sock_cc:
            msg = sock_cc.recvfrom(8192)
            client_cc=msg[1]
            if client_serv is not None:
                if msg[0] != b'keep alive':
                    sock_serv.sendto(msg[0], client_serv)

        # something from the remote server
        if s is sock_serv:
            msg = sock_serv.recvfrom(8192)
            client_serv=msg[1]
            if client_cc is not None:
                sock_cc.sendto(msg[0], client_cc)
```

The client client script

```
import socket

from select import select

DEST_IP = 'x.x.x.x' 
DEST_PORT = 8881 
LOCAL_IP = '127.0.0.1' 
LOCAL_SERVICE = 8800

sock_remote = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) sock_remote.connect((DEST_IP,DEST_PORT)) sock_local = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) sock_local.connect((LOCAL_IP,LOCAL_SERVICE)) sockets = (sock_remote, sock_local) for s in sockets:
    s.setblocking(0)

# loop forever forwarding packets between the connections while True:
    avail, _, _ = select((sock_local, sock_remote), (), (), 1)

    # send a keep alive message every timeout
    if not avail:
        sock_remote.send(b'keep alive')
        continue

    for s in avail:
        # something from the local server, forward it on
        if s is sock_local:
            msg = sock_local.recv(8192)
            sock_remote.send(msg)

        # something from the remote server
        if s is sock_remote:
            msg = sock_remote.recv(8192)
            # don't forward keep alives to local system
            if msg != b'keep alive':
                sock_local.send(msg)
```

Thanks again to Sam Mason for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: yup, was thinking you would want something like this!  it made it more complicated and I was worried about the first few packets being important for bringup so didn't think it was worth including in the version I posted.  might make a few stylistic improvements, but it looks functionally fine

Comment: this is nice but in this way machine A must reach machine B, if both A and B are behind firewalls then the only way is to use webrtc/stun/turn to connect the two :D